# Input element into char array using a variable

Tags: c, arrays, char

I need to input an element into a `static const char [].` I've tried with `snprintf`, `strcat` but it not working on my case because char array contains some `NULL` characters.

```
    char SBP_BASE_LAT[] = "surveyed_position""\x00""surveyed_lat""\x00";
```

I have variable *position_lati* of type `float` and I want to input it into *SBP_BASE_LAT*, like

```
    float position_lati = 43.456745;
    char SBP_BASE_LAT[] = "surveyed_position""\x00""surveyed_lat""\x00"["%f",position_lati];
```

What is the solution?
Thanks;

Comment: "_I want to input it into_" is unclear. Do you want to place it in the string? Then use `sprintf`. If the null characters are a problem, then turn your array into an array of strings.

Comment: It is not possible. If you add NULL you will make termination. Create an char array or remove NULLs from data that you want to add and use ```sprintf```.

Comment: _I've tried with snprintf, strcat but it not working_. If you show that not working code, we might be able to tell you why it is not working.

Comment: Just what `static const char[]` are you talking about?  You don't present any in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration you presented ...

```
char SBP_BASE_LAT[] = "surveyed_position""\x00""surveyed_lat""\x00";
```

... declares `SBP_BASE_LAT` as an array of `char`, with size derived from its initializer -- 32, including the additional terminator, if I have counted correctly.  The array elements are not `const`.

It is legal to include null bytes in the array's initializer as you do, but the *usefulness* of doing so seems doubtful.  All standard functions that handle strings will interpret the first embedded null byte as a string terminator, and if that's what you intend then it's unclear why you present a longer initializer.

> I have variable position_lati of type float and I want to input it into SBP_BASE_LAT [...]

You cannot do this via an initializer, because initializers must be compile-time constants.  You could do it at runtime like so:

```
float position_lati = 43.456745;
/* plenty of extra space to append the formatted value: */
char SBP_BASE_LAT[50] = "surveyed_position""\x00""surveyed_lat""\x00";
int base_lat_end;

/* 
 * compute the combined length of the first two zero-terminated
 * segments of SBP_BASE_LAT
 */
base_lat_len = strlen(SBP_BASE_LAT) + 1;
base_lat_len += strlen(SBP_BASE_LAT + base_lat_len) + 1;

/*
 * Format the value of position_lati into the tail of
 * SBP_BASE_LAT, following the second embedded zero byte.
 */
sprintf(SBP_BASE_LAT + base_lat_len, "%9.6f", position_lati);
```

Of course, that all supposes that the value of `position_lati` is not known until run time.  If it is known at compile time then you can just put that value literally into the array initializer.

Also, if your array were actually `const`, then you could not modify its contents after intialization, so a `sprintf()`-based approach such as I describe would not work.

Comment: Thank John, on my project, I use libsbp to connect with GPS receiver Swift-nav.  To configurer, I need to write into GPS receiver a message of this format <i>[SECTION SETTING, SETTING, VALUE]</i>. A NULL-terminated and delimited string with contents.